# Is there a way to select one value and other same values transform to null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 connected tables and I have a single query to get a values from them. All of them have duplicates. Now I need all duplicates from 2 tables, but from third table I want to get only first distinct value and other to transform to NULL.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
  operacije.nazivEng, slike.img_name, izvestaji.operacija 
FROM izvestaji 
  INNER JOIN operacije
    ON izvestaji.operacijaId=operacije.id 
  INNER JOIN slike 
    ON izvestaji.id=slike.izvestajId 
WHERE izvestaji.operacija IN (
    SELECT operacija 
    FROM izvestaji 
     WHERE projekatId='8' 
        AND datum='2019-10-03' 
     GROUP BY operacija) 
  AND izvestaji.projekatId='8' AND izvestaji.datum='2019-10-03' 
GROUP BY slike.img_name,operacije.nazivEng, izvestaji.operacija 
ORDER BY operacije.nazivEng DESC;
```

see the image

[image: Image of table]

I tried this also

```
SELECT 
  operacije.nazivEng, slike.img_name, izvestaji.operacija 
FROM izvestaji 
  INNER JOIN operacije 
    ON izvestaji.operacijaId=operacije.id 
  INNER JOIN slike 
    ON izvestaji.id=slike.izvestajId 
WHERE izvestaji.operacija IN (
           SELECT DISTINCT operacija 
           FROM izvestaji 
          WHERE projekatId='8' AND datum='2019-10-03') 
       izvestaji.operacija IN (
                 SELECT operacija 
                 FROM izvestaji 
                 WHERE projekatId='8' AND datum='2019-10-03' 
                 GROUP BY operacija) 
     AND izvestaji.projekatId='8' AND izvestaji.datum='2019-10-03' 
GROUP BY slike.img_name,operacije.nazivEng, izvestaji.operacija 
ORDER BY operacije.nazivEng DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL version 8.0 or greater, You can easily achieve this with LAG analytical function -

```
SELECT operacije.nazivEng
      ,slike.img_name
      ,CASE WHEN izvestaji.operacija <> LAG(izvestaji.operacija) OVER(PARTITION BY operacije.nazivEng ORDER BY slike.img_name)
                 THEN izvestaji.operacija
            ELSE
                 NULL
       END operacija
FROM izvestaji 
INNER JOIN operacije ON izvestaji.operacijaId=operacije.id 
INNER JOIN slike ON izvestaji.id=slike.izvestajId 
WHERE izvestaji.operacija IN (SELECT operacija 
                              FROM izvestaji 
                              WHERE projekatId='8' 
                              AND datum='2019-10-03' 
                              GROUP BY operacija)
AND izvestaji.projekatId='8'
AND izvestaji.datum='2019-10-03' 
GROUP BY slike.img_name
        ,operacije.nazivEng
        ,izvestaji.operacija 
ORDER BY operacije.nazivEng DESC;
```

Comment: I get this error 
```#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.operacija
FROM izvestaji
INNER JOIN operacije ON izvestaji.operacijaId=opera' at line 7
```
but if I remove izvestaji.operacija before "FROM" then I get this error

```
#4018 - No order list in window specification for 'lag'
```

Comment: Can you please try now?

Comment: This works perfectly on localhost. Thanks. But on my online server I get this error.
```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER(PARTITION BY operacije.nazivEng ORDER BY slike.img_name)
                 ' at line 3
```
Do you know what can be a problem here?

Comment: What is your MySQL version? I have mentioned this in the answer also, window functions are only allowed on version 8.0 or higher.